# Postgres pgAdmin4 and table maintenance fails

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

I just loaded Postgres 9.6 for a dev db and using pgAdmin4 I cannot run any table maintenance at all.  I added the path in the binary and it continues to fail.  Please help as I have no idea how to fix this one. Any ideas?

***Path to the binaries***

[image: Binary Settings]

*Error message I cannot get around.*

[image: error i keep getting]

On another dev box using pgAdmin3 I do not have this issue. I really do not understand what is happening.

If I use pgAdmin 3 I have no issue at all on the same machine.  Here are the screenshots on the same machine with pgAdmin3.

***pgAdmin3 Settings***

[image: pgAdmin3]

*Results*

[image: results]

I'm using:

Version1.1
Python Version2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec 5 2015, 12:54:16) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
Flask Version 0.11.1

Comment: AFAIK the maintenance tasks on pgAdmin issue SQL commands (like VACUUM, ANALYZE, CLUSTER, ...) and don't need access to the binaries. Those are only used for things such as Backup and Restore. So, sorry not to be helpful, but I think you might have to look in another direction.

Comment: Any ideas as to where?  Everything works fine on the same machine with pgAdmin3.  It is odd to say the least.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I have been able to vacuum, analyze, reindex and cluster one (smallish) database. I am using pgAdmin 4 1.1 on macOS 10.12.2. (Which, by the way, feels more responsive than the Windows version I had tried until now). Which versions are you using?

Comment: FWIW I had a similar problem and was able to use the CLI to perform maintenance, EG 
    vacuumdb my_database

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be another bug in a famously buggy product.

Comment: Not the OP's fault though? I mean, if we're talking about marking as off-topic all buggy products, that's all the questions about MySQL screwed for a start! :-)